# Quickbooks IPP v3 Invalid Line TaxCode in the request

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Using the IPP v3 I am trying to submit an invoice with multiple lines with different taxcode(s), I am getting the following error when submitting an invoice with 2 lines with TaxCodeRef mapping to existing TaxCode(s).

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2015-06-11T00:32:48.687-07:00">
  <Fault type="ValidationFault">
    <Error code="6100" element="Line.SalesItemLineDetail.TaxCodeRef">
      <Message>Invalid Line TaxCode in the request</Message>
      <Detail>Valid line TaxCodes for US should be TAX or NON. Supplied value: 8</Detail>
    </Error>
    <Error code="6100" element="Line.SalesItemLineDetail.TaxCodeRef">
      <Message>Invalid Line TaxCode in the request</Message>
      <Detail>Valid line TaxCodes for US should be TAX or NON. Supplied value: 9</Detail>
    </Error>
  </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Here is the submitted XML, TaxCode with Id 8 and 9 are defined and active.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Invoice xmlns:ns0="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <ns0:TxnDate>2015-06-11</ns0:TxnDate>
  <ns0:Line>
    <ns0:LineNum>1</ns0:LineNum>
    <ns0:Description>Product1</ns0:Description>
    <ns0:Amount>54.95</ns0:Amount>
    <ns0:DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</ns0:DetailType>
    <ns0:SalesItemLineDetail>
      <ns0:ItemRef>20</ns0:ItemRef>
      <ns0:UnitPrice>54.95</ns0:UnitPrice>
      <ns0:Qty>1</ns0:Qty>
      <ns0:TaxCodeRef>8</ns0:TaxCodeRef>
    </ns0:SalesItemLineDetail>
  </ns0:Line>
  <ns0:Line>
    <ns0:LineNum>1</ns0:LineNum>
    <ns0:Description>Product2</ns0:Description>
    <ns0:Amount>54.95</ns0:Amount>
    <ns0:DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</ns0:DetailType>
    <ns0:SalesItemLineDetail>
      <ns0:ItemRef>20</ns0:ItemRef>
      <ns0:UnitPrice>54.95</ns0:UnitPrice>
      <ns0:Qty>1</ns0:Qty>
      <ns0:TaxCodeRef>9</ns0:TaxCodeRef>
    </ns0:SalesItemLineDetail>
  </ns0:Line>
  <ns0:CustomerRef>58</ns0:CustomerRef>
</ns0:Invoice>
```

Is it possible to submit one invoice with multiple lines having different TaxCodes for Quickbooks online ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong question. You're asking:

> Is it possible to submit one invoice with multiple lines having different TaxCodes for Quickbooks online ?

But the error is telling you:

> Valid line TaxCodes for US should be TAX or NON. Supplied value: 9

So the problem isn't that you're submitting different tax codes. The problem is that you're submitting an *invalid* tax code.

You submitted:

`<ns0:TaxCodeRef>9</ns0:TaxCodeRef>`

When the only valid submissions are:

`TAX` or `NON`

e.g.

`<ns0:TaxCodeRef>TAX</ns0:TaxCodeRef>`

or

`<ns0:TaxCodeRef>NON</ns0:TaxCodeRef>`

There are no other valid values for QuickBooks Online *in the USA*. Only `TAX` and `NON`.

For QuickBooks Online *outside of the USA* this behavior differs a little in that other countries support a different set of tax does (e.g. GST, HST, PST, etc.)

Comment: Good point, what I am trying to do is submit an invoice with different tax rates for different lines. I am selling from California and some customers have different tax rates per shipping address, is it possible to have one invoice to cover multiple purchase orders from the same customer that have different tax rates ?

Comment: With QuickBooks Online USA, I don't think so. With QuickBooks Online outside of the USA, yes. You *might* be able to do it by specifying a sales tax item *as a line item* instead of in the actual tax item fields (this works in QuickBooks for Windows, but I'm about 98% sure it won't work in QuickBooks Online).

Comment: Tried with NON for TaxCodeRef and it worked. Seems like to we have to handle taxcodes for US separately with some extra codes and logic. Thanks @KeithPalmerJr.

Answer (score 1):

For US Quickbooks organisation/company, tax rates is handled differently. You need to create or add separate logic for US Locale:

See below from quickbooks US documentations:

[https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/manage-sales-tax-for-us-locales](http://eveloper.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/manage-sales-tax-for-us-locales)

And this is the non US documentation which was your code followed:

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/manage-sales-tax-for-non-us-locales#specifying-sales-tax