# Quickbooks installation, USA?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I have come across an issue with tax codes, and viewing the following SO topic I managed to discover the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719239/405764

However, the question now arises, as to if its possible to tell if the installation is a USA installation or not, from the API. Is there an endpoint I can use to find this out?

When I say "USA" installation, I am referring to the locale of the company. For instance, you can create sandbox companies (see image:)

[image: sandbox companies]

I currently have an application environment setting that I can switch on and off based on the installation, but I would much prefer it to be automated.

Anyone? Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuit provides a `CompanyInfo` endpoint you can use to get this data.

- Docs: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/companyinfo

Specifically, the response looks something like this:

```
{
  "CompanyInfo": {
    "SyncToken": "4", 
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "LegalAddr": {
      "City": "Mountain View", 
      "Country": "US", 
      "Line1": "2500 Garcia Ave", 
      "PostalCode": "94043", 
      "CountrySubDivisionCode": "CA", 
      "Id": "1"
    }, 
    "SupportedLanguages": "en", 
    "CompanyName": "Larry's Bakery", 
    "Country": "US", 
    "CompanyAddr": {
      "City": "Mountain View", 
      "Country": "US", 
... etc. etc. etc.
```

Where the important bit in there is the `Country` attribute, which is documented as:

```
Country
String
Country name to which the company belongs for financial calculations.
```

Comment: I looked at this endpoint and I assumed it was for interrogating clients within the system. Thanks @keith-palmer-jr guess I should have read the docs closer!